# Why is my JS scroll animation not working in my Django template?

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to do a scroll animation with js in django template that start counting when scrolling down and its not working

this is my html

```
    <section  class="numc">
        <div class="nums">
            <div class="num" data-goal="50">0</div>
            <div class="num" data-goal="60">0</div>
            <div class="num" data-goal="100">0</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="{% static 'javascript/js.js' %}"></script>
```

and this is js code

```
let nums = document.querySelectorAll(".nums .num");
let section = document.querySelector(".numc");


window.onscroll = function () {
    if (window.scrollY >= section.offsetTop) {
      nums.forEach((num) => startCount(num));
    }
};

function startCount(el) {
    let goal = el.dataset.goal;
    let count = setInterval(() => {
        el.textcontent++;
        if (el.textcontent == goal) {
            clearInterval(count);
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: Change `el.textcontent++; if (el.textcontent == goal) { clearInterval(count); }` to `if (el.textContent == goal) { clearInterval(count); return; } el.textContent++;`.

Comment: *While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.*